# EnOcean Java Library

Tags: java, raspberry-pi, osgi, osgi-bundle, iot

I am looking for an EnOcean JAVA library that supports the EEP:D2-01-08 or that is well documented for adding a new EEP profil and that also works on both devices the USB 300 and EnOcean PI.

I found:
https://github.com/aleon-GmbH/aleoncean
but unfortunately it does not support the EnOcean Pi as mentionned in its documentation.

and the:
https://github.com/dog-gateway/enj-library
that I did not yet tested, any one have tested? or anyone have worked with another library?

Thanks a lot for your help!